# The solution of a convex optimization problem is unique

Tags: convex-optimization

There is a statement in a thesis I am reading,

> The solution of a convex optimization problem is unique, and the global and the local minima are essentially the same.

Is there a proof for it? Why does it hold?

Comment: This claim is simply false. Also what do you mean by "essentially the same" ?

Comment: I think what may have been meant is that _any local minimum is also a global minimum_ and that a **strictly** convex objective function has at most one global minimum. 
See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337090/if-f-is-strictly-convex-in-a-convex-set-show-it-has-no-more-than-1-minimum

Answer (score 3):

The statement is not true! For example, the convex problem: $$\min_{x} f(x) ,$$ such that $f(x)$ is given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } -1 < x < 1 \\ \lvert x\rvert -1 , & \mbox{ otherwise} \end{cases}$$

has infinitely many local/global minima.